# Predeploy JetBrains ReShaper Activation Method 'Use License Server' Setting in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, jetbrains-ide

We're using the latest (currently 2023.3.3) versions of JetBrains ReSharper/ReSharper C++ on our workstations along with "JetBrains Floating License Server" to handle licensing.

We're using the `JETBRAINS_LICENSE_SERVER` environmental variable for license server discovery as specified [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/license_server/configure_automatic_server_discovery.html#add-an-environment-variable), unfortunately users still have to explicitly select `Use License Server` when they first start Visual Studio after the deployment.

[image: JetBrains License Activation Dialog in Visual Studio]

I've already been in touch with JetBrains support:

> ReSharper will require activation on the first launch. Unfortunately, no automation mechanism could configure activations before the launch.

Now I am wondering if anyone still figured out a way to predeploy this setting.
i.e. by editing some config-file, setting some registry-keys (I know about the VS-private registry hive) etc.

so far I've looked into

- `%appdata%\JetBrains`
- `%localappdata%\JetBrains`
- win registry
- `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<config>\privateregistry.bin`

but wasn't able to find *this* setting.

Comment: JBRS also has a community forum - maybe x-posting there can help: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366389-ReSharper-Community

Comment: thanks for the hint, - x-post on JBRS community forum done: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/16750074156306-Predeploy-JetBrains-ReShaper-Activation-Method-Use-License-Server-Setting-in-Visual-Studio